# How Do You Simulate Typing in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-capture

I am thinking of making a few video turorials on C#, my problem is that I don't type very fast and I don't want to put the user to sleep as they watch me typing in real-time.

I would like to write a small C# program that will take a line of text and feed it to the keyboard buffer, so that I can simulate keyboard typing.

Does anyone know how to access the keboard buffer to do this?

If this has been done before or if someone knows of an existing program to do this, can you point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Time-lapse video (to hell with the SendInput and SendKeys answers). Time-lapse videos always look funny and people like watching them. Plus, you can have funny music play during the speeded-up parts! :)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - especially the Benny Hill theme.

Comment: can you record it ahead of time instead of broadcasting in real-time? if not, sendkeys may be your only hope, but it will be awkward.

Comment: When you are a carpenter every problem looks like a nail. ;)

Comment: You could just use your clipboard.   Or have you considered just learning how to type?

Comment: I've watched many YouTube video tutorials where people simply pre-type all of their comments into notepad, and copy/paste them when the time comes. This seems like a very over engineered solution to a simple problem. Also, I've never really been bothered by a slow typer during a video either, so the problem you may be avoiding could simply be non-existent!

Answer (score 3):

You should use SendKeys, i can show you how to use

here is an example: `SendKeys.Send('A');`

but u can use it with your own character: `SendKeys.Send(CHARACTER HERE);`

what happens if we have a string variable, you will get nothing

if it happens use it this way:

```
string letter = "exampleletter";
foreach (char ch in letter) 
   SendKeys.Send(ch.ToString());
```

i hope it works for you

Yogibear

Answer (score 1):

At PDC and other conferences I've been at, they make liberal use of code snippets to quickly drop the new code into place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
[SendKeys Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Provides methods for sending keystrokes to an application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that you can write to keyboardbuffer or something like this

what I know it to send to some windows some keyboard commands
in your case it will be sending keyboard commands to notepad probably
in that case use the function provided above

but I would recommend to cut video parts (typing moments) out of your video
instead of writing code in C#